# Why is 's a verb?

Tags: pos-tagging

I'm using a NLP tool called Spacy to parse the parts of speech for some sentences. I am new to linguistics so please bear with me.

The parser is splitting, for example, `it's` into `it` as a pronoun and `'s` as a verb.

I don't really understand why `'s` is a verb.

Here is an example:

```
Well, if that's how it's going to be, then I'm out!
Well INTJ
, PUNCT
if ADP
that DET
's VERB
how ADV
it PRON
's VERB
going VERB
to PART
be VERB
, PUNCT
then ADV
I PRON
'm VERB
out PART
! PUNCT
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are these two sentences the same to you?

1. It's fine.
2. It is fine.

If so, then I would claim that they are synonymous because `'s` is written shorthand for `is`. `Is` is the verb `to be` in English.

Comment: That is perfectly clear: is the the verb "to be". Thank you. I suppose whoever downvoted my question didn't think "I am new to linguistics so please bear with me." was reasonable.

Answer (score 4):

Because "that's" can always be replaced by "that is". When *'s* is not a possessive, it is a shortened version of "is" or "has" (or, in rapid speech after *what* and *when*, "does").